# Compare two Alphanumerical mysql columns (Find postcode district between range)

Tags: mysql, postal-code

I have a mysql database that contains a range of postcode district ranges.
I am trying to find the row that matches the given district, in this example 'SY18'.
I have mysql query below, but it returns both the values in the table because the fields are alphanumeric.

`SELECT rate FROM table WHERE district_from <= 'SY18' AND district_to >= 'SY18'`

Table example

```
id    district_from    district_to    rate
1     SY1              SY9            10
2     SY16             SY22           20
3     AL1              AL99           37
4     B1               B99            37
5     BB1              BB99           37
6     CB1              CB99           40
```

How do I return only correct results?

Comment: Normalize your codes by numeric part zerofill - i.e. not `SY1` but `SY01`. Then you may use BETWEEN operator.

Comment: @Akina  I tried adding LPAD but I still get both results?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT( LEFT(district_from, 2), LPAD(SUBSTRING(district_from, 3), 2, '0')) <= 'SY18' AND CONCAT( LEFT(district_to, 2), LPAD(SUBSTRING(district_to, 3), 2, '0')) >= 'SY18'`

Comment: Does the prefix is **always** `SY`? Or maybe it may vary but **always** is 2-char?

Comment: @Akina I have updated the question with a few more examples in the table. Prefix can change any letter one or two characters. A1-A99 to X1-X99.

Comment: A valid postcode district can also contain a letter at the end of the string, e.g. `WC2B` is the postcode district for `WC2B 4AB`. Do you need to consider any valid postcode district?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR` to skip first characters of the string and then `+0` to consider the value as a number. Example:

```
SELECT v
FROM
(SELECT 'SY1' v UNION SELECT 'SY16') t
WHERE SUBSTR(t.v, 3)+0 > 10
;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work with my data. The table in the example is not complete and the data contains many text number combinations in this format A1-A99, AA1-AA99.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION normalize_district (district VARCHAR(4))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT( TRIM(TRAILING CASE WHEN 0 + RIGHT(district, 2) > 0 
                                  THEN RIGHT(district, 2)
                                  ELSE RIGHT(district, 1) END FROM district),
               LPAD(CASE WHEN 0 + RIGHT(district, 2) > 0 
                         THEN 0 + RIGHT(district, 2)
                         ELSE 0 + RIGHT(district, 1) END, 2, '0') );
```

and then

```sql
SELECT *
FROM district_to_test
LEFT JOIN rate ON normalize_district(district_to_test.district) 
                         BETWEEN normalize_district(district_from)
                             AND normalize_district(district_to);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8379bc3ec2a9b49afdf5662ef0114cb7)

---

`0 + RIGHT(district, 2) > 0` in the function thecks does the last 2 symbols in `district` are digits.

If true then 2-digit number wil be extracted by RIGHT(), and the whole expression value will be above zero (you claim that there is no values like `'AA0'` or `'AA00'`).

If false, and only one digit is present, then RIGHT() will give a substring which is started from a letter, and the value will be zero.

Based on this I divide the whole value to a prefix and numeric postfix, and add a zero to the numeric part making it 2-digit unconditionally. Such value can be used for direct string comparing by BETWEEN operator.

---

The goal of a function is to convert the value to `'AA00'` format. For this purposes we must divide the whole value to textual and numeric parts and normalize (zero-pad) the latter one.

You may use any other dividing method. For example, you may check does the value contains two digits using `LIKE '%\\d\\d'`. Or backward, you may determine does the value contains two letters using `LIKE '\\D\\D%'`... these methods have relatively equal difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, I'm not too afraid to admit this is way over my head. Can you provide any explanation of this code?

Comment: @Lightning_young Some explanations added.